# Adding java facet for a GAE maven project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I created a Google App Engine maven project according to [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) documentation and it works successfully. Then after i import the same project into eclipse  by using the option **Existing Maven Project** . But in eclipse its only just maven project without having java facet.Then i manually added facet by right clicking **Project -> Properties -> Project Facet -> Tick on java option**. Now eclipse shows java errors on my created application (for some app engine related classes). But this project works fine by using maven command like **mvn clean install** and **mvn appengine:devserver**. Here follows the pom for my maven project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine.demos</groupId>
  <artifactId>guestbook</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.0</appengine.target.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
      <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <modules>
    <module>guestbook-war</module>
    <module>guestbook-ear</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not appear to have any dependencies in you pom. These define the libraries your application depend on. Minimally, for an appengine war, you'll need something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GAE Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you also want to do some unit testing, you'll need to add the following to the above block:

```
            <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If you want to work in eclipse, make sure you have the wtp-m2e eclipse plugin installed, and the Google Plugin for Eclipse plugin installed. They'll make your life much easier.

Comment: Note that the Google Plugin for Eclipse tool is now deprecated, so you should be using the [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) plugin instead.